# Prisma raw query return number instead of found value

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

This is the query that I am executing

```
const jobs = await this.prisma.$executeRaw`
SELECT
  name
 FROM 
  jobs 
 WHERE 
  status = 'ACTIVE'`;
```

but instead of getting the results that macth this query I only get a number, so the type of `jobs` is number and its value is 1. I am using postgresql

Comment: Where/How is this column `name` updated?  Can you show that code ?  (or some proof that the column `name` does not have the value `1`)

Comment: @Luuk it is updated when the job is created in a different service and it is a string. When I removed WHERE, the result was 3 because it then had more matches in database and instead of taking those, it is counting them

Comment: The _different service_  must be wrong (updating/inserting the wrong value... )

Comment: Turns out I've been using the wrong method. It was .$queryRaw for retrieving from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code to use the `$queryRaw` method instead;

```
const jobs = await this.prisma.$queryRaw`
SELECT
  name
 FROM 
  jobs 
 WHERE 
  status = 'ACTIVE'`;
```

Comment: Works, but you can't use variable in queryRaw, if your query is stored in variable then use $queryRawUnsafe(variablehere)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I was using wrong method so instead of `.$executeRaw` I should have used `$.queryRaw`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `executeRawUnsafe` instead of `queryRawUnsafe`. Both methods returns different data.

`executeRawUnsafe` - Executes a raw query and returns the number of affected rows.

`queryRawUnsafe` - Performs a raw query and returns the SELECT data.

For eg.

```js
const query = `SELECT * FROM "Table"`;
const data = await prisma.$queryRawUnsafe(query); // this returns all rows from Table
```